# How can I format a number for multiple prints in python3.x?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, printing, format

I want to be able to format a number a certain way and have it turn out this way for each print function I call rather than reformat it within each print function.  I just see it as a way to clean up for code a little. Here's an example:

Given the variable:

```
weight = mass * conversion_const
```

and say it comes out to over 2 decimal places.

Then I want to print:

```
print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is too heavy' %(format(weight, ',.2f')))
print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is too light' %(format(weight, ',.2f')))
print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is just right' %(format(weight, ',.2f')))
print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is wayy to heavy' %(format(weight, ',.2f')))
```

This is just for an example, it would be in a `if` statement if I were to create something that needed these responses, but as you can see, either way I would have to format the same variable each time. How can I avoid this?

Comment: why don't you pre-compute `format(weight, ',.2f')`?

Comment: Didn't even think of that to be honest, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
weight = "%.2f"%(mass * conversion_const)

print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is too heavy'%(weight))
print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is too light'%(weight))
print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is just right'%(weight))
print('The mass of the load is %s Newtons, which is way to heavy'%(weight))
```

or even better:

```
weight = "The mass of the load is %.2f Newtons, which is "%(mass * conversion_const)

print(weight + 'too heavy')
print(weight + 'too light')
print(weight + 'just right')
print(weight + 'way too heavy')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few options of how to extract the common formatting code, just for example:

```
ANSWER_FORMAT = 'The mass of the load is {0:,2f} Newtons, which is {1}'
format_answer = ANSWER_FORMAT.format

print(format_answer(right_weight, 'just_right'))
print(format_answer(heavy_weight, 'too heavy'))
```

(Notice, how the new formatting style can make life easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Format it once, store the formatted string in a variable, then use that variable.

Comment: The OP asked for help formatting a string and your answer to him was to format it?

Comment: @IanAuld the OP knows how to format a string, he was asking to help with avoiding the redundancies, and that's what Stefan is suggesting.

Comment: Regardless, SO is supposed to be a canonical repository of answers. Any future readers may not know how to format a string and this answer would be of no use to them or anyone else looking to learn how to format a string.

Comment: If I could up vote your answer I would but I don't have the rep yet. Thanks though that's what i was looking for.

Comment: @IanAuld I don't get you. Every answer has to be seen in the context of the question. And the question already shows how to format. I answer exactly what was asked, what was left to complete the picture.